# wine (64bit prefix) fails url opening from the app

Tags: 22.04, wine, 64-bit, systemd, xdg-open

Launching KSPLauncher (Kerbal space program) everything works smoothly except  this ...

---

***every time I want to open some web links I see jumping firefox icon near my cursor for 3 seconds then nothing happening***

---

##### Each attempt spawns such log (using `journalctl -xef`)

***Is there any way to see what was passed inside this job?***

```
Jan 12 04:27:22 kexix systemd[1339]: Started Firefox Web Browser - Web Browser.
░░ Subject: A start job for unit UNIT has finished successfully
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░ 
░░ A start job for unit UNIT has finished successfully.
░░ 
░░ The job identifier is 737.
```

---

##### wine logs remains clear, this action spawns nothing

```
~/Games/epic-games-store/drive_c/Program Files/Epic Games/KerbalSpaceProgram/English$ wine Launcher --verbose
042c:fixme:ntdll:NtQuerySystemInformation info_class SYSTEM_PERFORMANCE_INFORMATION
042c:fixme:imm:ImmReleaseContext (000000000007006A, 000000000003007A): stub
MESA-INTEL: warning: Performance support disabled, consider sysctl dev.i915.perf_stream_paranoid=0

042c:fixme:wbemprox:client_security_SetBlanket 00000001ED4A0E40, 00000000015C9010, 10, 0, (null), 3, 3, 0000000000000000, 0
042c:fixme:wbemprox:client_security_Release 00000001ED4A0E40
04bc:fixme:kernelbase:AppPolicyGetThreadInitializationType FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFA, 000000006776FE10
04bc:fixme:avrt:AvSetMmThreadCharacteristicsW (L"Audio",000000006776FDB8): stub
042c:fixme:win:RegisterTouchWindow hwnd 000000000007006A, flags 0 stub!
042c:fixme:wbemprox:client_security_SetBlanket 00000001ED4A0E40, 00000000015C9CC0, 10, 0, (null), 3, 3, 0000000000000000, 0
042c:fixme:wbemprox:client_security_Release 00000001ED4A0E40
042c:fixme:wbemprox:wbem_services_CreateInstanceEnum unsupported flags 0x30
042c:fixme:wbemprox:wbem_services_CreateInstanceEnum unsupported flags 0x30
042c:fixme:wbemprox:wbem_services_CreateInstanceEnum unsupported flags 0x30
```

---

##### I have following regedit tweaks:

1. HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\https\shell\open\command

   - key: (Default)

     - string: "C:\windows\system32\winebrowser.exe" -nohome "%1"
2. HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\http\shell\open\command

   - key: (Default)

     - string: "C:\windows\system32\winebrowser.exe" -nohome "%1"
3. HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Wine\WineBrowser

   - key: Browsers

     - string: xdg-open

---

##### Installed via winetricks:

```
$  winetricks list-installed
Executing mkdir -p /home/kex
------------------------------------------------------
warning: You are using a 64-bit WINEPREFIX. Note that many verbs only install 32-bit versions of packages. If you encounter problems, please retest in a clean 32-bit WINEPREFIX before reporting a bug.
------------------------------------------------------
Using winetricks 20220411-next - sha256sum: 013a9062d25b07ab3cc5d60e664bd171899a397a8614fa953bc2b8e9a9fff049 with wine-8.0-rc3 (Staging) and WINEARCH=win64
cinepak
w_workaround_wine_bug-24013
d3dcompiler_43
d3dx11_43
d3dx9
vcrun2008
dirac
remove_mono internal
winxp
dotnet40
remove_mono internal
dotnet48
d3dcompiler_47
dxvk
l3codecx
winhttp
andale
arial
comicsans
courier
georgia
impact
times
trebuchet
verdana
webdings
corefonts
w_workaround_wine_bug-26925
msxml3
msxml4
msxml6
fontfix
vcrun2005
vcrun2010
vcrun6
vcrun6sp6
fontsmooth=rgb
```

---

##### System info:

```
$ wine --version
wine-8.0-rc3 (Staging)

lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy
```

Comment: nice format on the question! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok seems like it is a wine64 prefix "feature" xD because on wine32 prefix winebrowser runs perfectly ...

```
WINEARCH=win32 WINEPREFIX=~/.wine32 wine winebrowser https://www.google.com/
# open url in default browser SUCCESS =)

WINEARCH=win64 WINEPREFIX=~/.wine wine "C:\windows\system32\winebrowser.exe" "https://google.com"
# same behavior as was described in this question -- FAIL, dies silently =(
```

anyway you could resolve this with some workarounds on win64 prefix like these:

---

##### temporary easy solution 1 which I'm using now == "gvim stdin text buffer"

1. download && install [gVIM](https://ftp.nluug.nl/pub/vim/pc/gvim90.exe)
2. HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\https\shell\open\command

   - key: (Default)

     - string: cmd.exe /c echo %1 | "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim90\gvim.exe" -
3. HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\http\shell\open\command

   - key: (Default)

     - string: cmd.exe /c echo %1 | "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim90\gvim.exe" -
4. launch app, click on button -> you'll see gvim window with a url, double click, right click, copy & paste in your browser, close gvim

---

##### idea for better solution 2 == "watchdog script"

1. save stdin to some links.txt from http && https regedit shell\open\command (via gVim or notepade.exe like in the first solution)
2. implement script on some programming language (python? go? etc) which should watch links.txt changes and do subprocess call on '\r\n' which will launch your browser with url == previous line

---

##### Cheers && be safe && let the Wine be with you xD